# How do I set a Silverlight Grid layout ColumnDefinition width to "*" programatically?

Tags: silverlight, dynamic, grid, width

So I'm creating columns dynamically for a Grid layout in Silverlight (V3.0, C#):

```
LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
```

and you can specific that the width of the column be "auto" with

```
LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
```

But how to you set it to be "*" (share with with other columns)?

I know you can set this in the XAML, but how do you do it in code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pass a GridLength with a GridUnitType of Star:

```
new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) };
```

Bonus is that this technique also supports proportional spacing i.e. the equivalent of XAML 2*, 3*, etc.